# Bind collection of models to a table

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

So I've started looking into backbone.js for the first time today. One of the things I'm keen to get stuck into is binding model properties to useful controls. My question really is how to go about bindind individual model properties to controls.

I came up with an example of this where you can bind a collection of any model to a table choosing which properties to ignore, however I have a feeling I'm not going the right way about this. The idea is to eventually extend this and make the table editable like a data grid. I've added this to JSFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/yqjvK/

**I use a helper function to generate templates for the model. This is used to generate table headers and row data**

```
 //helper function to loop through a model's attributes choosing which to ignore
 function LoopAtts(model,func,ignore){
     //calls func on each unignored model attribute
  }
```

**This is a basic model I use to illustrate the example**

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: function() {
  return {
       firstName: "N/A",
   lastName:"N/A",
   score:function(){
    return 0;
   }
  };
},        
});
```

**This is a view I use to print out a model's cell data, it listens to when a property is changed and for now just sets the html to the updated value.**

```
var RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  className: "rowView",
  initialize: function() {
    var cells = LoopAtts(this.model,CellTemplate,this.options.ignore);
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.change);
    this.$el.html(_.template(cells)(this.model.attributes));
  },
  change:function(e){
console.log(e);
for(p in e.changed)
{
    if(e.changed.hasOwnProperty(p))
    {
        //handle update of cell
        this.$el.find("#"+p).html(this.model.attributes[p]);
    }
}

 }
});
```

**This is a view I use to bind to collections, adding rowViews when elements are added to the collection.**

```
var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    defaults: {noData:'<tr><td>No Data</td></tr>'},
    tagName: "table",
    firstTime: true,
    initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(People, 'add', this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(People, 'reset', this.addAll);
    this.$el.html(this.noData);
  },      
addOne: function(o) {
  //singleton for table data
  if(this.firstTime)
  {
    var headers = LoopAtts(o,HeaderTemplate,this.options.ignore)
    this.$el.html(_.template(headers)(o.attributes));
    this.firstTime = false;
  }
  //assign view to model and append it to the table
  var view = new RowView({model: o,ignore:this.options.ignore});
  this.$el.append(view.render().el);
},
addAll: function() {
  this.model.models.each(this.addOne, this);
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For list view rendering I would recommend taking a look at how [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) solved these problems, eliminating list generation boilerplate in your code.

Comment: Specifically, I would look at Marionette's Composite View (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) and Item View. (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md). https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md#compositeviews-itemviewcontainer shows how to build an html table.

Comment: Also see http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/ for an article on how to create tables using Marionette's Composite View.